Using PowerPivot to compute test coverage
For my current project I am using Excel and Pivot Tables quite often. Now, I have seen the nice feature PowerPivot in Excel and I am thinking to use it in my project.
Especially, I want to use PowerPivot to compute the test coverage of my system tests.
For every requirement of my system I have a description. Every requirement is tested by at least one test case with a description on how to perform the testcase.
There is a mapping which requirement is tested with which test case. In the end there is also a test execution where every test case is performed and has the state FAIL or PASS.
For this I have basically four tables, which are simplified here for the ease of explanation:
System Requirements Table:



REQ_ID
REQ_Text




REQ_A
Req Text A


REQ_B
Req Text B


REQ_C
Req Text C



Test Case Table:



TC_ID
TC_Text




TC_1
Test case 1


TC_2
Test case 2


TC_3
Test case 3


TC_4
Test case 4



Requirements to Test Case Mapping:



REQ_ID
TC_ID




REQ_A
TC_1


REQ_A
TC_2


REQ_B
TC_1


REQ_B
TC_3


REQ_C
TC_4



Test execution:



TC_ID
Outcome




TC_1
FAIL


TC_2
FAIL


TC_3
PASS


TC_4
PASS



Now I want to use PowerPivot to compute my requirement coverage, i.e. I wanted to know for a certain requirement the number of FAILED and PASSED Testcases.
I tried this with the PowerPivot datamodel 2 and also linked the different tables with 1 .. n relationships.
But the printed statistics just show the total number of all executed test cases FAILED and PASSED being completely unrelated to the requirements 1. Maybe this is just not possible or the scope of Power Pivot or I am doing something completely wrong.
Can someone here please try to help me out with this issue. It would be a great thing if I can utilise PowerPivot for this problem.


